# Contact Form 7 Wordpress Accessible

Tags: wordpress, accessibility, contact-form-7

I have 2 problems with Contact Form 7 and accessibility.

Without changing the core code of the plugin:

1. How can I stop the error message from fading away when I mouseover them?
2. The error message is currently being generated in a span right next to the input, any way to make it appear IN the label? Otherwise a screen reader won't ever read it.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these might require core code editing from the sounds of it.

> The error message is currently being generated in a span right next to the input, any way to make it appear IN the label? Otherwise a screen reader won't ever read it.

I don't recommend doing this. What I recommend is seeing if the `<span>`s have their own `id`, if so you can probably write some JS function that looks for either the `id` and add the `aria-describedby="spanIDhere"` to the associated `<input>`. Or if the `<span>` don't have one, generate one, then insert it like mentioned.

Most AT will read it as `<label>` text, text in the `span` denoted by the ID, form element type.

Comment: Not every AT understand(s) ARIA so generating messages in their label should be more compatible afaik

Comment: More and more do. The only one that really doesn't is ZoomText. Unless you make the added `span` far away from the form element and you the user is greatly zoomed in.